# How can I make my app be full screen on Huawei Mate 10 Pro, or other 18:9 ratio phones?

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen, display

I tried forcing "Full Screen" in my styles like this:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

I tried from my activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

I even tried this, which makes the intent that would get called when I press on the "full screen display" button :

```
public static boolean goToFullScreen(final Activity activity) {
    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    try {
        if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
            final Intent huaweiIntent = new Intent();
            huaweiIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.settings.HwChangeButtonActivity"));
            if (huaweiIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                activity.startActivity(huaweiIntent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.appendLog("goToBatterySettings exception:" + e.getMessage(), "E", Constants.OTHER);
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I always get this [Screenshot](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/yEa6LtrbE0wIeGw/upload.png)

Any ideea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the `<application>` element:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: nope, does not work, it looks the same.
The app is "full screen" as in it has no status bar. But it doesn't cover the 18:9 ratio, just "full screen" as 16:9, having the black thing at the bottom